# Best way to create array with a range of number (Double Type) in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to create a range number for an array. The data type is Double, not Int.
it looks like: `[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0....]`

Now I am doing like

```
val arraydataInt=1 to 1000 toArray
val arraydata = arraydataInt.map(x=>x.toDouble)
```

I am just not sure if the way is efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Doubles in the range

```
1d to 1000d by 1d toArray
```

Comment: Weirdly, IIUC, this counts using BigDecimal, then calculates the value to insert (from IndexedSeq) as (start + step * i) in BD then converts to double. (That's the iterator; Iterable.copyToArray just stuffs the values in the array.)

Answer (score 4):

Iterate or tabulate, take your pick.

```
Array.iterate(1.0,1000)(1.+)
// or
Array.tabulate(1000)(1.0.+)
```

Comment: I'd pick tabulate. Or `foreach` just steps thru: `val vs = Array.ofDim[Double](1000) ; for (i <- 1 to vs.size) vs(i-1) = i` or less likely `(1 to 1000).iterator.map(_.toDouble).copyToArray(vs)`.

Comment: @som-snytt, Range->Iterator[Int]->Iterator[Double]->copy-to-Array[Double]. Is that all? Maybe `(1d to 1000d by 0.5).filter(_%1d == 0d).copyToArray(vs)`?